# Variable for absolute path and Alias for a command in one string or scrip?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

or in other words, how to cat files from a long path directory

```
cd /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt
cat test.txt | grep abc
```

How do I shorten this?

I tried with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="/media/home/user/usb/locuments/linux/test.txt"
var2="cat test.txt | grep abc"

"cat test.txt"=`var1 var2"
```

or

```
"cat test.txt"=`cat test.txt | grep abc`
```

LOL ... Obviously don't have even a basic knowledge about scripting

There should be some other ways of doing this

What would be the best method to use for this to work?

what do I start to search and try for?

Comment: Are you just looking for `grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt`?

Comment: I am trying to use `cat test.txt | grep abc` , and abc is a text from file test.txt, and that file is  located in /media/home/user/usb/Documents/linux/

Comment: Yes, so isn't `grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt` what you are looking for? There is no need for `cat` and no need to `cd` into the directory. You can just run `grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt` from wherever you are. Or do you want to do this with a single command? Do you want to be able to run `foo` and have that execute `grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt`?

Comment: oh yes, `grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt` does the job.
which is great as I don't have to cd to the folder. Thank you!
But now how do I make it short? it is a file located in USB stick and I will have to extract info from this file plenty of times. And the command is quite long to type it every time. So is it foo I am looking for? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always need to run that exact command, you can use an alias. Run `nano ~/.bashrc` and add this line to the file:

```
alias abc='grep abc /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt'
```

Save the file, open a new terminal and you will now be able to just run `abc` and get your results.

If you need to be able to search for different patterns, use a function instead. Again, run `nano ~/.bashrc` and add these lines (but delete the alias above if you have added it):

```
function abc(){
    grep "$@" /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt
}
```

Save the file, close it, open a new terminal and you can now run:

```
abc foo # search /media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt for 'foo'
```

To search for the string `foo` in the file `/media/home/user/usb/Documents/Linux/test.txt`. Or

```
abc bar # search
```

To search for the string `bar`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Your script does exactly what I need Only little problem I had was that I didn't know I have to run `source ~/.bashrc` after saving the bashrc file. Felt pretty stupid because the 'abc' didn't work and I checked the line few times. I will learn more about shell scripting. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @brkroot that's why I explicitly wrote "open a new terminal" after both of the solutions I gave :). The `~/.bashrc` is read (sourced) each time you start a new shell session and the easiest way to do that is to open a new terminal.

Comment: actually yes, I didn't open a new terminal, but typed in another already open one. But now I got the idea and purpose of opening new terminal. Although I still can source the bashrc in the current terminal after I close nano :).  Anyway, I am getting right into experimenting with different functions now. got so much to do